# How to get all nodes for a matching node value in a xml using javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

Most of the examples online,  have a javascript that calls the xml document with evaluate method which passes a xpath and returns specific node values.
I need to get all the parent elements for the matching node value in xpath.

For eg:

user.xml:

```
<users>
<user>
 <Id>0</Id>
 <Name>Bob</Name>
</user>
<user>
 <Id>1</Id>
 <Name>Keith</Name>
</user>
<user>
 <Id>2</Id>
 <Name>John</Name>
</user>
<users>
```

javascript:

```
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            showResult(xhttp.responseXML);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "user.xml", false);
    xhttp.send(); 

    function showResult(xml) {
        var txt = "";
        path = "/users/user[Id>0]/Id";
        if (xml.evaluate) {
            var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

            var result = nodes.iterateNext();

            while (result) {                
                txt += result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
                result = nodes.iterateNext();
            } 
        // Code For Internet Explorer
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {            
            xml.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
            nodes = xml.selectNodes(path);
            for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                txt += nodes[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
            }
        }           
    }
```

Expected result: I need to get the xml like (`var users= xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("user");` but filtered based on a value)

```
<users>
<user>
 <Id>1</Id>
 <Name>Keith</Name>
</user>
<user>
 <Id>2</Id>
 <Name>John</Name>
</user>
<users>
```

Since I didnt get any answer, I simplify my question.

How to write an xpath to get the parent node for the matching node.
I tried //*[Id='1'], but it returns

```
 <user><Id>1</Id>..</user>.
```

I also need to include

```
 <users></users>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess,you will have to iterate from the collection returned by getElementsByTagName and compare with your value to filter the items out.

Comment: I can do that. But I have a functionality that is same as in if and else conditions within the for loop. So I have to filter the xml before the for loop. So I thought of using the var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

instead of the xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("user");